# jQuery Datatable sorting "invalid month" error

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

i've got an error when sorting my datatable. Datatable is detecting and interpreting strings in my columns for sorting.

Example : a column with users lastnames, one of my User is called "Decxxxxx", Datatable is detecting the firsts 3 letters "Dec" in my user lastname and interpreting my column as a date (Dec > December), even if i force the type in TypeDefs as a String and not a date it does nothing.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-euro-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x;
        if ( $.trim(a) !== '' ) {
            var frDatea = $.trim(a).split(' ');
            var frTimea = frDatea[1].split(':');
            var frDatea2 = frDatea[0].split('/');
            x = (frDatea2[2] + frDatea2[1] + frDatea2[0] + frTimea[0] + frTimea[1] + frTimea[2]) * 1;
        }
        else {
            x = Infinity;
        }
        return x;
    },
    "date-euro-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },
    "date-euro-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
});

var oTable = jQuery('.dataTable').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "bFilter": true,
    "bRetrieve":true,
    "columns" : columnDefs,
    "aoColumns": columnSort,
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, "tous"]
    ]}
);
```

with :

```
columnDefs = [null, null, null, null, null, Object { sType="date-euro"}, null, null](ligne 940)
columnSort = [Object { bSortable=false}, null, null, null, null, null, Object { bSortable=false}, Object { bSortable=false}]
```

the column incriminated is the 2nd.

The error : "Error: Invalid month string" on the first row of the 2nd colunm with value "Declercq" with contain "Dec" from "december".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mootools bug. You will find an explanation and 
the solution if you read the article below:

http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support-menu/tabulizer-tips/52-invalid-month-string-error-solution